# android StatusBar elements color does not appear

Tags: android, statusbar, android-appcompat

I'm trying to do like this: https://material-design.storage.googleapis.com/publish/material_v_4/material_ext_publish/0Bx4BSt6jniD7WVQ2WXFLeUtxSlE/style_color_themes_light2.png (using that theme) (light)

I don't know why the status bar elements does not appear (or the elements have the same color as the colorPrimaryDark)

I use Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar and Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar

With Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar elements are white and with Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar too, I guess.

**My style file:**

```
<resources>

    <style name="MyStyle" parent="MyStyle.Base">

    </style>

    <!-- Tema Base -->
    <style name="MyStyle.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/primary_dark</item>
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/primary</item>
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/fondo</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/accent</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

**My style file for API 21+:**

```
<resources>

    <style name="MyStyle" parent="MyStyle.Base">
        <item name="android:colorPrimaryDark">@color/primary_dark</item>
        <item name="android:colorPrimary">@color/primary</item>
        <item name="android:colorAccent">@color/accent</item>
        <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/colorPrimario</item>
        <item name="android:textColorSecondary">@color/colorSecundario</item>
        <item name="android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds">true</item>
        <item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
        <item name="android:windowContentTransitions">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowAllowEnterTransitionOverlap">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowAllowReturnTransitionOverlap">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowSharedElementEnterTransition">@android:transition/move</item>
        <item name="android:windowSharedElementExitTransition">@android:transition/move</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

Answer (score 0):

API 23+ required.

in `styles.xml` 
`<item name="android:windowLightStatusBar">@color/colorBrawn</item>`